# How can i change download location of mRpostman package fetch_attachments() function in R?

Tags: r, filepath, shiny-server, gmail-imap

In Rstudio if i try

```
library(mRpostman)
library(tidyverse)
con <- configure_imap(
  url = "imaps://imap.gmail.com",
  username = "username@gmail.com",
  password = "password"
)
con$list_server_capabilities()
con$list_mail_folders
con$select_folder(name = "INBOX")
res <- con$search_since(date_char = "18-Jan-2022")
res %>% con$fetch_attachments()
```

I can get username@gmail.com file only on "current work path"
I want to download it into "www" file so i can use same code at shiny-server.

```
<No>
current work path-----test.Rporj
                   |
                   ---www
                   |
                   ---username@gmail.com---INBOX
<Yes>
current work path-----test.Rproj
                   |
                   ---www---username@gmail.com---INBOX
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi! mRpostman author here. This is a simple feature that, unfortunately, is not implemented yet. Would you mind opening a ticket at [https://github.com/allanvc/mRpostman/issues/] ?